# How can we store the value of a Modal in Pycord (2.x) in a method/function and then return it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

```py
class title_input_modal(Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Audio Title Input")

        self.add_item(InputText(label = "Audio Title", style = discord.InputTextStyle.short))

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        
        val = self.children[0].value
        await interaction.response.send_message(val)
```

How can I make a method and store the value of the response? If I try accessing `title_input_modal.children[0]` from another cog's class method, this error pops up:-

```
Ignoring exception in view <View timeout=180.0 children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.primary: 1> url=None disabled=False label='Play' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='▶️' id=None> row=None>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chinmay Krishna\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 371, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "d:\Programming\python\intellij\intellij_python\AxC-777-Music\no_upload.py", line 137, in play_button_callback
    print(title_input_modal.children[0].value)
AttributeError: type object 'title_input_modal' has no attribute 'children'
Ignoring exception in view <View timeout=180.0 children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.primary: 1> url=None disabled=False label='Play' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='▶️' id=None> row=None>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chinmay Krishna\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 371, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "d:\Programming\python\intellij\intellij_python\AxC-777-Music\no_upload.py", line 137, in play_button_callback
    print(title_input_modal.children[0].value)
AttributeError: type object 'title_input_modal' has no attribute 'children'
```

Comment: Use global variables.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @BrainFlooder?

Comment: Like a file call `__init__.py` in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the value in your class as a property and access it once the modal has been dismissed.
To do so you will have to modify your class like this.

```
class title_input_modal(Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Audio Title Input")
        
        #
        self.val = None

        self.add_item(InputText(label = "Audio Title", style = discord.InputTextStyle.short))

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        
        self.val = self.children[0].value
        await interaction.response.send_message(val)
        self.stop()
```

Then from where you call your modal, you will have to initialise it like this so that you can then access its properties

```
title_modal = title_input_modal()
await ...send_modal(title_modal)
await title_modal.wait()
print(title_modal.val)
```

Without the **stop** and **wait** methods, your bot won't wait for the modal interaction to be over, so you won't be able to access the value from the user.